# wget not displaying all website data

Tags: html, shell, cygwin, wget

Input: `wget -qO- http://runescape.com/community | grep -i playerCount`

Output: `<li class="header-top__right-option"><strong id="playerCount">0</strong> Online</li>`

In browser: [image]

Using cygwin..I am trying to use wget to pull a number out of a webpage. As shown in the example above, the playerCount is 0. If you actually load the webpage up and look at the same code, it is a completely different number. How can I get the real number? I was told it may be something with cookies or a user agent. This just started not working a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That value appears to be filled in via javascript (though I can't find the request at a quick glance). If that's the case then you cannot get it with something like `wget` or `curl` in this way. You would need to find the specific request and send that.

Given the URL indicated by aadarshs (which I saw but mistested when I looked at it the first time) something like this should work.

```
curl -s 'http://www.runescape.com/player_count.js?varname=iPlayerCount&callback=jQuery000000000000000000000_0000000000000' | awk -F '[()]' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: As far as the jQuery part goes. Why is it a bunch of 0's?

Comment: That's just a "callback" function name that the result contains. The original request contains some number that was selected via some method. The format of the callback name matters (try removing any characters and the request fails). So, for simplicity and clarity, I just used all zeros for the necessary digits.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
curl http://runescape.com/community | grep -i playercount
```

EDIT: Adding the player count link

```
curl http://www.runescape.com/player_count.js\?varname\=iPlayerCount\&callback\=jQuery111004241600367240608_1434074587842\&_\=1434074587843
```

Comment: That got you the 70k number and not 0?

Comment: Added the curl address for getting player count. Hope it helps.

Comment: That URL does return the correct value but needs "parsing".